# Truffle "Replacing" durring migration

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-migration, migration, tutorials

what does "Replacing" mean in migration?

a simple test contract C.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract C{
    uint public ConstructorUint;

    function C(uint SetConstructorUint)public{
        ConstructorUint = SetConstructorUint;
    }
}
```

the Migration file 99_migration.js:

```
var Cnumber0 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber1 = artifacts.require("C");
var Cnumber2 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber3 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber4 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber5 = artifacts.require("C"); 

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber0, 0);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber1, 1);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber2, 2);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber3, 3);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber4, 4);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber5, 5);    
}
```

the truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

upon starting up Ganache and running in the terminal.

```
$ truffle migrate --network development
```

I find that create contracts happened, as expected.

in the terminal running.

```
$ truffle networks
```

I find only One C contract with the last at address of the C contracts.
starting over by closing Ganache and running

```
$ truffle networks --clean
```

this time I try

```
$ truffle develop
```

this opens the truffle console where 
from the truffle console

```
truffle(develop)> migrate
```

I see this:

> Saving artifacts... Running migration: 99_migration.js   Deploying
>   C...   ...
>   0xf56571c947f71fa8d3220ce2707accdf97a00a3ac2042d18dcff0410e26bf476
>   C: 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10   **Replacing** C...   ...
>   0x17acd2015ea93445bca90c4f207073a7f86eb3556de00936e78f6fd4fe67c7a3
>   C: *0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf*   **Replacing** C...   ...
>   0xcc2a645db6d4c32405ab3c771069262370512689de895a6374b78b72d73b12c8
>   C: 0x8f0483125fcb9aaaefa9209d8e9d7b9c8b9fb90f   **Replacing** C...   ...
>   0xac0d4f51c458e28fc3ecc871994e03e3aed86032dd881cf7dd57f2dffb58d378
>   C: 0x9fbda871d559710256a2502a2517b794b482db40   **Replacing** C...   ...
>   0xf6cded7c4228a00cc2f12287417b0c697dec09635c013e28440d10dea7fc0565
>   C: *0x2c2b9c9a4a25e24b174f26114e8926a9f2128fe4*   **Replacing** C...   ...
>   0x539e27630c8881957a07ded94f9f2fb60963e505991eec1a588893e96d80b654
>   C: *0x30753e4a8aad7f8597332e813735def5dd395028* Saving successful
>   migration to network...   ...
>   0x68e7f2440f71ec0386d4214eb0c3e2346112dd1073495fc2ef1c8244691e5684
>   Saving artifacts...

again that Replacing word
so I use the functions of the contracts by *"ContractName.at("ContractAddress").FunctionName(FunctionArguments)*

```
truffle(develop)> C.at("0x30753e4a8aad7f8597332e813735def5dd395028").ConstructorUint()
```

> { [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] }

```
truffle(develop)> C.at("0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf").ConstructorUint()
```

> { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] }

```
truffle(develop)> C.at("0x2c2b9c9a4a25e24b174f26114e8926a9f2128fe4").ConstructorUint()
```

> { [String: '4'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 4 ] }

as you can see the numbers 5, 1, and 4 do exist. so the contracts do too?
however from a separate terminal I again check the network by

```
$ truffle networks
```

and I get this:

> Network: UNKNOWN (id: 4447)   C:
>   0x30753e4a8aad7f8597332e813735def5dd395028   Migrations:
>   0x8cdaf0cd259887258bc13a92c0a6da92698644c0

only one contract at the last address? so what happens in a non test net does the contract deploy with migrations many times with different constructor values as expected or does it do something else unexpected.
if it does the unexpected what is a work around to accomplish multi deployment of the same contract, such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Nice observation, `deployer.deploy(Cnumber0, 0);` will create smartcontract and deployed in the network. It doesn't matter how many times you called.

And every contract will have a unique id and unique datastore. So as per your deployment code

```
var Cnumber0 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber1 = artifacts.require("C");
var Cnumber2 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber3 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber4 = artifacts.require("C"); 
var Cnumber5 = artifacts.require("C");



module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber0, 0);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber1, 1);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber2, 2);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber3, 3);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber4, 4);
    deployer.deploy(Cnumber5, 5);    
}
```

you want to deploy 5 smart contract's with different args. So as per my above explanation. Eth will maintain separate state for every smartcontract. So that a reason when you invoke you will get different values.

Once contract is deployed you can't modify the contract logic. So while writing contract we need to be little careful.